# Use two javascript files in the same openlayers map

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, openlayers

I am working on two examples provides by the community of OpenLayers here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/
Here is the first script (Geolocation):

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Geolocation from 'ol/Geolocation';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';

var view = new View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2,
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }) ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});

var geolocation = new Geolocation({
  // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
  trackingOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  },
  projection: view.getProjection(),
});

function el(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

el('track').addEventListener('change', function () {
  geolocation.setTracking(this.checked);
});

// update the HTML page when the position changes.
geolocation.on('change', function () {
  el('accuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAccuracy() + ' [m]';
  el('altitude').innerText = geolocation.getAltitude() + ' [m]';
  el('altitudeAccuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAltitudeAccuracy() + ' [m]';
  el('heading').innerText = geolocation.getHeading() + ' [rad]';
  el('speed').innerText = geolocation.getSpeed() + ' [m/s]';
});

// handle geolocation error.
geolocation.on('error', function (error) {
  var info = document.getElementById('info');
  info.innerHTML = error.message;
  info.style.display = '';
});

var accuracyFeature = new Feature();
geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function () {
  accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
});

var positionFeature = new Feature();
positionFeature.setStyle(
  new Style({
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 6,
      fill: new Fill({
        color: '#3399CC',
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  })
);

geolocation.on('change:position', function () {
  var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
  positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ? new Point(coordinates) : null);
});

new VectorLayer({
  map: map,
  source: new VectorSource({
    features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature],
  }),
});
```

and here is the second script (Draw_features):

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Draw from 'ol/interaction/Draw';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';

var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
});

var source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});

var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});

var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

var draw; // global so we can remove it later
function addInteraction() {
  var value = typeSelect.value;
  if (value !== 'None') {
    draw = new Draw({
      source: source,
      type: typeSelect.value,
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
  }
}

/**
 * Handle change event.
 */
typeSelect.onchange = function () {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  addInteraction();
};

document.getElementById('undo').addEventListener('click', function () {
  draw.removeLastPoint();
});

addInteraction();
```

My main goal is to use both scripts to create just one map that show the user his geolocation and enable him to draw some features.

I tried writing this index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Draw Features</title>
    <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
    
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 800px;
        height:400px;
        position : relative
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div>
  </div>

  <label for="track">
    track position
    <input id="track" type="checkbox"/>
  </label>
  <p>
    position accuracy : <code id="accuracy"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    altitude : <code id="altitude"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    altitude accuracy : <code id="altitudeAccuracy"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    heading : <code id="heading"></code>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    speed : <code id="speed"></code>
  </p>

  <form class="form-inline">
    <label for="type">Geometry type: &nbsp;</label>
    <select class="form-control mr-2 mb-2 mt-2" id="type">
      <option value="Point">Point</option>
      <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
      <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
      <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
      <option value="None">None</option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-control mr-2 mb-2 mt-2" type="button" value="Undo" id="undo">
  </form>
 
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
   

    <script src="draw_features.js"></script>
    <script src="geolocation.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

But all i get is two maps one bellow the other and not one map : see image below
[image]

So my questions are :

- Is it possible to combine both scripts to create one map (without merging the two scripts in one file)
- How to avoid re importing modules in script 2 that were already imported in script 2

Comment: Both scripts create a new map `var map = new Map(.....)`  Unless you want two maps you will need to merge the scripts to create a single map with both functionalities.

Comment: You could refactor both scripts to functions that recieve a map and then write a inline script that creates a map and invokes these functions with the map

Comment: Sound like some great ideas thank you guys